# How can I prevent angularJS from squelching script errors?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On my AngularJS sample project, I know that I have a service method which SHOULD throw a JavaScript error.

Using Firebug, I confirm that a JS error is thrown when resolving a promise from a $resource (TypeError: phone.images is undefined); but, the error never appears in the Firebug console.

How can I get the resource to 'fail fast' and propagate the error up the call stack?

Here is the service code:

```
var phonecatServices = angular.module('phonecatServices', ['ngResource']);

phonecatServices.factory('Phone', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('phones/:phoneId.json', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{phoneId:'phones'}, isArray:true}
    });
  }]);
```

Here is the controller (which fails silently):

```
phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Phone',
  function($scope, $routeParams, Phone) {
    $scope.phone = Phone.get({phoneId: $routeParams.phoneId}, function(phone) {
      //JS error SHOULD be thrown here:
      $scope.mainImageUrl = phone.images[0]; 
    });

    ...
}]);
```

I don't want the code to fail silently! How can I fix it?

Ideally, I would like to fix it throughout the framework, rather than putting in special error handling code for each service or resource call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the error callback to your `get` call:

```
Phone.get({phoneId: $routeParams.phoneId}, function(phone){
  // Do Stuff with phone object
}, function(error) {
  alert("Y U NO RETURN PHONE?");
  // Handle error accordingly
});
```

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource) for `$resource`

If you'd like to generically handle errors for AJAX requests through the angular framework, then you'd probably like something like an [http interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) (Check the interceptors section). This kind of paradigm requires that all requests pass through your interceptor service to be handled in a generic fashion.

Comment: Somewhere in the future, at a support desk far far away, there will be an IT help desk ticket entered: "When the user tries to view the phone details, they encounter an error message: Y U NO RETURN PHONE?"